# Why can't I close pipes after wait?

Tags: c, process

I am trying to understand how `wait()` works. This is the a c program that mimics `ls -F -1 | nl` in command line

```
    pipe(fd); // create the pipe

    pid1 = fork(); //fork child 1

    if (pid1 == 0) // child 1
    {
        close(fd[0]);                       // close read end of the pipe
        dup2(fd[1], 1);                     // child 1 redirects stdout to write to the pipe
        execlp("ls", "bin/ls", "-F", NULL); // execute ls -F
        close(fd[1]);                       // close write end of the pipe
    }

    pid2 = fork(); //fork child 2

    if (pid2 == 0) // child 2
    {
        close(fd[1]);                  // close write end of the pipe
        dup2(fd[0], 0);                // child 2 redirects stdin to read from the pipe
        execlp("nl", "usr/bin", NULL); // execute nl
        close(fd[0]);                  // close read end of the pipe
    }

    if (pid1 != 0 && pid2 != 0) // parent process
    {
        wait(NULL);   // wait for a child
        wait(NULL);   // wait for another child
        close(fd[0]); // close read end of parent pipe
        close(fd[1]); // close write end of parent pipe
    }
```

I initially thought the order of `wait(NULL)` and `close(fd)` doesn't matter. But apparently does. Why this code keeps running without printing anything while moving the two `wait(NULL)` below the `close(fd[1])` works fine?

Comment: Isn't this the same code you posted yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434790/using-the-data-in-the-pipe-as-the-argument-of-the-function

Comment: You didn't even change the obvious problems I pointed out then, like trying to run code after `execlp()`.

Comment: You don't need the last `if()`. The children both use `execlp()` so they'll never get there.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, I did change it as you suggested. I deleted the argument and yeah this time I'm trying to understand how wait() works

Comment: You still have `close(fd[0])` after `execlp()`

Comment: The child commands won't get EOF if the parent has the pipes open, so the `wait()` calls won't return, so the closes won't be executed.  The parent is not going to use the pipes; it must close all the pipe descriptors before it waits for its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nl` won't exit until it gets EOF on `stdin`. This won't happen until both the parent and child 1 close the write end of the pipe. Child 1 will do this when it exits, the parent does this when it does `close(fd[1])`.

So you've got a deadlock. You won't close the FD until the second `wait()` returns, but it won't return until you close the FD.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thank you!